# If a person dies unnatural death accident or by murder, then is it also due to his/her karma?

Tags: death, life

We know that if a person does good or bad karma then he/she has to suffer during his time of death. So if a good person dies unfortunately by an accident or if he is murdered then does that also is happening to him due to his past or current life karma ?

Comment: every thing that happens to us is a result of our actions from the past. whether that past is yesterday, or previous birth, we don't know. Only Bhagavan does.